# angular js filter inside ng-change

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-change

my data template looks like this,

```
scope.items=[{"name:"John","score":1},{"name":"Rick","score":5},{"name":"Peter","score":2}]
```

I have a select box with values 0,1,2,3,4,5 and would like to filter `items object` based on `score value` selected in dropdown

```
scope.scores= [
                {
                    "name":"condition 0",
                    "value":"0"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 1",
                    "value":"1"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 2",
                    "value":"condition 2"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 3",
                    "value":"3"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 4",
                    "value":"4"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 5",
                    "value":"5"
                }
            ]
```

HTML

```
 <select  id="scoreS"  ng-model="score" ng-change="updateScore()">
                    <option
                            ng-repeat="score in scores"
                            value="{{score.value}}">{{score.name}}</option>
                </select>
```

So when i select `condition 0` from my dropdown box I need to filter `items` to show only those objects matching score(key) 0 and when I select 1 from the drop down , match only items having score(key) 1 and so on. how do you do this inside updateScore() function ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. it's better use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` in `drop-down`

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items=[
  {"name":"John","score":1}
,{"name":"Rick","score":5}
,{"name":"Peter","score":2}
]

$scope.scores= [
                {
                    "name":"condition 0",
                    "value":"0"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 1",
                    "value":"1"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 2",
                    "value":"2"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 3",
                    "value":"3"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 4",
                    "value":"4"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 5",
                    "value":"5"
                }
            ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl as vm">
<select  id="scoreS"  ng-model="score" ng-options="score.value as score.name for score in scores ">
                </select>
     <div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{score:score}">
     <span>{{item.name}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` option to filter the data according to drop down

`<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter :score">`

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.scores= [
                {
                    "name":"condition 0",
                    "value":"0"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 1",
                    "value":"1"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 2",
                    "value":"2"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 3",
                    "value":"3"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 4",
                    "value":"4"
                },
                {
                    "name":"condition 5",
                    "value":"5"
                }
            ]
$scope.items=[{"name":"John","score":1},{"name":"Rick","score":5},{"name":"Peter","score":2}]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select  id="scoreS"  ng-model="score" ng-change="updateScore()">
    <option ng-repeat="score in scores" value="{{score.value}}">{{score.name}}</option>
    </select> 
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter :score">
    {{item.name}}=  {{item.score}}
    </div>
</div>
```